# onEdit function not triggering Apps Script in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been able to successfully create a simple script to take values I enter on a sheet ("Input") set up as a form and populate another sheet ("Current") set up to retain the values in columnar fashion. On my PC it activates with a button on the form.

Now I am trying to execute the script when I access the same form on my android phone where the button doesn't work. I decided to use the `onEdit` function which I was able to successfully use in a test application, but when I transfer in the code from my PC-based application I get no action.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
      if (e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'F17') {
        return;
      }

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
var dataSS = ss.getSheetByName("Current");

//Input Values
var values = [[
formSS.getRange("D4").getValue(),
formSS.getRange("D8").getValue(),
formSS.getRange("E8").getValue(),
formSS.getRange("F8").getValue(),
formSS.getRange("D10").getValue(),
formSS.getRange("F10").getValue(),
formSS.getRange("I10").getValue(),
formSS.getRange("D15").getValue(),
formSS.getRange("E15").getValue(),
formSS.getRange("F15").getValue(),
formSS.getRange("D17").getValue(),
formSS.getRange("F17").getValue()
]];

dataSS.getRange(dataSS.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 12).setValues(values);

//Clear Values
formSS.getRange("D4").clearContent()
formSS.getRange("D8").clearContent()
formSS.getRange("E8").clearContent()
formSS.getRange("F8").clearContent()
formSS.getRange("D10").clearContent()
formSS.getRange("F10").clearContent()
formSS.getRange("D15").clearContent()
formSS.getRange("E15").clearContent()
formSS.getRange("F15").clearContent()
formSS.getRange("D17").clearContent()
formSS.getRange("F17").clearContent()

}
```

The plan is to use the entry of the last value ("F17") as the trigger to execute the script.

Comment: I posted an answer, but now I noticed that you check is "F17" field edited and that triggers the script that clears the content in the same field. Maybe you can skip that field and clear it with e.range.clear();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main difference between your local file and online file is that when you call

```
formSS.getRange(CELL_ADDRESS).getValue();
```

you make a request to the server, so you make many requests to the server during your script execution.
onEdit(e) function has its own limits [some details here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) so maybe (I did not tested it) it would be faster to do all data collecting with one line

```
var allDataInArray = formSS.getRange("D4:F17").getValues();
```

... and after that create your values[][] 2D array from allDataInArray ... place it in another sheet with your command

```
dataSS.getRange(dataSS.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 12).setValues(values);
```

... and set all values to "" in allDataInArray that you have done by clearContent() calls prevoiusly.

After that, you can make another request

```
formSS.getRange("D4:F17").setValues();
```

so all deleted content in allDataInArray will be pasted over values you deleted by clearContent() and other values will be replaced by own duplicate.

NOTE: I did not tested this variant...